# Android studio with libgdx and android libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to import an Eclipse project to Android Studio with libGDX.
My project has multiple library dependencies.
My structure is as follows:
androidLib1 -> androidLib2 -> appProject

I'm not using libGDX for multi-platform so in Eclipse I added all the resources to my androidLib1. 
I need that all my libraries and project be familiar with the libGDX resources.

In eclipse it works great. However in Android Studio once I run the app and start the libGDX activity I receive this exception:

```
11-27 13:49:26.170  14721-14721/? E/RPC-﹕ Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target: Linux, 32-bit
11-27 13:49:26.170  14721-14721/? E/RPC-﹕ at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:117)
11-27 13:49:26.170  14721-14721/? E/RPC-﹕ at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34)
11-27 13:49:26.170  14721-14721/? E/RPC-﹕ at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication.<clinit>(AndroidFragmentApplication.java:48)
11-27 13:49:26.170  14721-14721/? E/RPC-﹕ ... 19 more
11-27 13:49:26.170  14721-14721/? E/RPC-﹕ Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gdx: findLibrary returned null
11-27 13:49:26.170  14721-14721/? E/RPC-﹕ at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
11-27 13:49:26.170  14721-14721/? E/RPC-﹕ at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
11-27 13:49:26.170  14721-14721/? E/RPC-﹕ at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:113)
```

I think that for some reason the androidLib2 and appProject are not linked somehow with the gdx.jar. Which androidLib1 is linked too. If I try and link appProject to gdx.jar I receive a compile error of duplicate resources or something like that.

Note, that gdx.jar is a java jar...

Anyone have an idea how to get this to work?

Thanks.

Added the project gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14+'
    }
}

allprojects {

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        gdxVersion = '1.3.1'
        roboVMVersion = '1.0.0-alpha-04'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.3'
        ashleyVersion = '1.3.1'
        aiVersion = '1.3.1'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":androidLib1") {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the "build.gradle" file?

Comment: @AndroidGuy, I added the build file. Thanks.

Comment: Off-topic and opinion-based but i think that eclipse is better for libgdx development.

Comment: @nikoliazekter, you are probably right but I kinda have to move to android studio as I hit the limit of 65k methods in android (without proguard) and from what I understand the best way to run proguard in debug mode is with gradle. Besides, once I could get it started, gradle would be very helpful with my project.

Comment: @Raz, so if you need Gradle then maybe this can help http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44